# How to close com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I'm using sql server jdbc driver mssql-jdbc-9.2.1.jre8-sources.jar and create an object of `com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource`.

After setting it up with host-credential-etc, opening Connection and closing Connection, how do I close SQLServerDataSource object itself, I could not find any method in API.

https://javadoc.io/doc/com.microsoft.sqlserver/mssql-jdbc/9.2.1.jre8/com/microsoft/sqlserver/jdbc/SQLServerDataSource.html

Note to closer: I'm NOT using C3P0 connection pool, that may have close option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `SQLServerDataSource` is a simple data source that does not provide any form of connection pooling, it only serves as a factory of physical, non-pooled JDBC connections. As such, you do not need to close, destroy or otherwise dispose of this class (other than normal garbage collection).

The need to close a data source only exists for data sources that are backed by a connection pool (like c3p0), to release those pooled connections and maybe end house-keeping threads.